# ListPlot[] code for CSV file not working

Tags: list-manipulation, csv-format, plotting

I have a CSV file with $9$ columns. I want to plot them in the following way. Column $1$ will be along the $X$-axis. Any point $(x_i, y_i)$ of $i$-th curve in the plot will have the $x$ value from the corresponding  row of column $1$ and the $y$ value from the $x$-th row of the $(i-1)$-th column. So, there will be $8$ curves in the plot. The file could be downloaded [from this link](http://bit.ly/1tSqSU3). The code is:

```
data = Import["iso-pair-data.csv", "CSV"]; ListPlot[{data[[All, 2]],
data[[All, 3]], data[[All, 4]]}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

I am not getting the plot as expected. Any help?

Comment: I think this is what you're trying to do: `ListPlot[Rest@Transpose@data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full]`

Comment: I do not get it. Lets say i=2, ok? So the first column is the x-values, fine. Now the y-values you are saying come from the rows of the `(i-1)` column? but this is `1` in this case? But that is supposed to be the `x-values` for all the other columns. Are you simply trying to plot columns 2-9 against the first column?

Comment: @Nasser It should be `i+1`... if you use all the information in the question I don't think there can be any doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
data=Import[["iso-pair-data.csv"];
vals = Table[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, i]]}], {i, 2, 
Length@First@data}];
ListLinePlot[vals, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Max[data[[All, 2 ;;]]]}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]